# Understanding a few lines of JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. I want to write a JavaScript to calculate the area of various geometries.The program takes dimensions from a user.I want to know the what does [0] show in following line:

```
document.getElementsByName('ID OF INPUT FIELD')[0].value;
```

Can anyone give me name of this thing (i.e array so something else !) so that I can learn it or please give me a link to understand this.

```js
<script>
function func() {
var base = document.getElementsByName('width')[0].value; // ---> what [0] shows? 
var height = document.getElementsByName('height')[0].value;
var out = (1/2) * parseFloat(base) * parseFloat(height);

document.getElementsByName('output')[0].value= out;


}
</script>
```

```html
<body>
<html>
<br><center> <button onClick="func()">Calculate Area</button></center><br>

<table>
    
<tr><td align="right">Width (b):</td>
<td align="left"><input type="textbox" name="width"></input><br></td><br><br>

<tr><td align="right">Height (h):</td>
<td align="left"><input type="textbox" name="height"></input><br></td><br><br>



<tr>
<td align="right">The area is: </td>
<td align="left"><input type="textbox" name="output"></input><br>
</td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It gets the Node at the first position in the NodeList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByName('width')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), i.e. a list of nodes that have an attribute named `"name"` and value `"width"`. For your example HTML that will give you a `NodeList` of length 1, the first (and only) item being the text input box for the width:

```
<input type="textbox" name="width">
```

Because the `NodeList` is a list you can access its items by index. Indices are zero-based so `[0]` accesses the first item in the list, which we already know to be the width text input element.

The final piece of the puzzle is the use of `.value` which will return the contents of the text input element. This will be whatever value the user has entered into that input box. Therefore the result of:

```
var base = document.getElementsByName('width')[0].value;
```

is to create a variable named `base` which references the value entered into the first text input box with its `name` attribute set to `"width"`.

You can see the same technique being used to acquire the height and to write the result into the text box with `name="output"`.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName('width')` line  returns all the HTML dom elements with name `"width"` (and its a list).

So in your example it returns the element `<input type="textbox" name="width"></input>` element as a list. and you are using [0] to get the first element.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByName('width')` returns a NodeList of elements that have a `name` attribute that have the value of `'width'`

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByName api will return the collection of elements. Therefore [0] will return the first found element which is matched with the value of "name" attribute .
Example :

var base = document.getElementsByName('width')

"base" is the array contain all elements having attribute "name" = "width".
So if you want to access the first element , just write this line : base[0].